# laravel Application implements HttpKernelInterface

Tags: laravel

Why Laravel Application class need implements HttpKernelInterface？HttpKernelInterface methods is not used.

```
<?php
  namespace Illuminate\Foundation;

  class Application extends Container implements ApplicationContract, HttpKernelInterface
  {    
  }    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is.

[Here](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/HttpKernelInterface.php) is the definition for `HttpKernalInterface`. It defines the contract for the `handle()` method, which is the method that is responsible for turning a `Request` into a `Response`.

The `handle()` method is implemented in the `Application` class [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L800-L806).